# Setting process group prevents child process from starting

Tags: c, terminal, process, fork, exec

So I am trying to create a basic terminal, and my problem is this: if I use the following code to execute most "normal" terminal commands (e.g. `ls`, `cat`, etc), there are no issues. It sets the process group and works perfectly. However, when I try to execute a command such as `vim .`, it appears that the process immediately stops. If I remove the call to `setpgrp()`, the command works as expected (and executes with the `pgid` of the controlling terminal).

Here is my code:

```
pid_t normal_cmd(char **argv, int bg) {
    int pid = fork(), status;
    if(pid < 0)
            unix_error("Could not fork child process");
    else if(!pid) { //child (this is the problematic area)
            setpgrp();
            status = execvp(argv[0], argv);
            if(status < 0)
                    unix_error("Could not exec child process");
    }
    else { //parent
            if(!bg) {
                    addjob(jobs, pid, FG);
                    pause(); //waitpid() is in SIGCHLD handler
                    struct job_t *cj = getjobpid(jobs, pid);
                    if(cj && cj->state != ST)
                            deletejob(jobs, pid);
            }
            else
                    addjob(jobs, pid, BG);
    }
    return pid;
}
```

Any idea why changing the process group would cause vim to fail here?

Comment: Just a guess here, but  http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695299/functions/setpgrp.html suggest to me that maybe `setpgrp()` is creating a new session with no controlling terminal?

Comment: So the difference would be that vim requires a terminal while the others only need the standard I/O file streams.

Comment: @jwdonahue Thanks, that seems very possible! I'll see if I can figure out how to fix that issue.

Comment: I was just poking around in the search results for `[c]setpgrp` and noticed a comment that it has been deprecated by POSIX and `setpgid` should be used instead. That's the limit of my possible contributions here.  Good luck.

Comment: So I've tested this by replacing `setpgrp()` with `setpgid(getpid(),0)`, and opening `/dev/tty` within the child. Looks like the process does indeed still have a controlling terminal, at least until `execvp` is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vim` will try to read from the controlling terminal, and because its process group is not the foreground process group, it will receive a SIGTTIN signal which suspends it. `ls` and other "normal" commands aren't suspended because they don't read from stdin (which is the terminal in this case).

The setpgrp() call has the effect of creating a new process group with the calling process as its leader -- and the new process group is not the foreground process group on the terminal until you make it so with **tc**setpgrp() or ioctl(TIOCSPGRP).

You can read more about job control [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_mono/libc.html#Job-Control). Especially [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_mono/libc.html#Access-to-the-Terminal), which explains why a program in the background receives a SIGTTIN if it tries to read from the the tty, but not a SIGTTOU if it tries to write to it.